# How to pull an SVG linearGradient id from a map function

Tags: reactjs, svg, linear-gradients

I need to create a dynamic svg semi circle gauge with a linearGradient that reacts to changes in value. For the time being, these angles are passed as props and hardcoded.

I have an arc component that defines the semi circle. The arc is then rendered into the parent component that receives additional props.

I have defined a color's array which holds my gradient colors, in the parent component, I map through the colors array (three colors) and for each one, i render a  element with the contained attributes. I set the id dynamic using id={`linearColors${index}`}.

Now still in my parent component I again map through the colors and for each, render an arc component then pass it the attributes.

My question is, how can i access the linearGradient id from outside the map function to use as a stroke property in my arc map method?

The angle points for each stop are already defined. Will this method work?

```
var colForGradient = <G>{colors.map((color, index) => {
            const nextCol = colors[index + 1]
            if (!nextCol) {
                return null
            }
            console.log(nextCol, 'nextCol')
            console.log(color, 'color')
            return (

                <linearGradient key={index} id={`linearColors${index}`} x1={angles[0]} y1={angles[1]} x2={angles[2]} y2={angles[3]}>
                    <stop offset="0" stop-color={color}></stop>
                    <stop offset="1" stop-color={nextCol}></stop>
                </linearGradient>

)
// convert value to boolean and negate to true
}).filter((comp) => !!comp)
}</G>
```

```
var arcs = <G>{colors.map((color, i) => <Arc
            // style={"stroke: "}
            cx={256}
            cy={256}
            key={i}
            stroke={(id) => colForGradient(id)}
            strokeWidth={strokeWidth}
            color={color}
            startAngle={angles[i]}
            endAngle={angles[i + 1]}
            transform={transformCircleToDialFromDown}
            onClick={() => arcClick(i)}
            className="hover-highlight"
        />)}</G>;
```

Comment: What do you mean with *access the linearGradient id*? You created those ids by your own convention so your parent can create those same ids by the same convention also knowing the length of `colors`. Also the ids don't seem to be unique as they repeat for every `Arc` component. You should probably incorporate an arc id too.

Comment: So I managed to pass the id reference to arcs by rendering the colForGradient and referencing the color prop in arcs as  color={`url(#linearColors${i})`}/

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to pass the id reference to arcs by rendering the colForGradient and referencing the color prop in arcs as  color={`url(#linearColors${i})`}. The problem I have now is the gradients aren't showing dynamically.  In the log, the arcs seem to accept the angle points as offsets and the id of the linearGradient

```
 var colForGradient = <G>{colors.map((color, index) => {
            const nextCol = index < index.length - 1 ? colors[index + 1] : colors[index]
            if (!nextCol) {
                return null
            }
            console.log(nextCol, 'nextCol')
            console.log(color, 'color')
            return (

                <linearGradient key={index} id={`linearColors${index}`} x1="1" y1="0" x2="0" y2="1">
                    <stop offset={angles[index]} stop-color={color}></stop>
                    <stop offset={angles[index + 1]} stop-color={nextCol}></stop>
                </linearGradient>
            )
            // convert value to boolean and negate to true
        }).filter((comp) => !!comp)
    }</G>

    console.log(colForGradient, 'colgrad')


        // define linear gradients in array and map over them, rendering each path?
        var arcs = <G>{colors.map((color, i) => <Arc
            cx={256}
            cy={256}
            key={i}
            strokeWidth={strokeWidth}
            color={`url(#linearColors${i})`}
            stroke={`url(linearColors${i})`}
            startAngle={angles[i]}
            endAngle={angles[i + 1]}
            transform={transformCircleToDialFromDown}
            onClick={() => arcClick(i)}
            className="hover-highlight"
            />
            )
        }</G>;
```